# HTTP error 500 in a small WordPress site

Tags: 500-internal-error

I'm having a 500 error on my site and I tried to solve it doing the following:

- Deleted the `.htaccess` file.
- Deactivated all the plugins
- Uploaded a fresh `wp-admin/` and `wp-includes/` folder.

None of these steps worked, I don't know what else to do because I can't even enter the `/wp-admin` URL.

What else can I do?

Comment: One important info is missing: What has happened that led to the error in the first place? Did you try to update something? Were you editing files on the server? Please update your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: What is the error message? Please check the server logs and separate PHP error log if you have one, and / or define WP_DEBUG to true in your wp_config.